# Creating index that considers simultaneous elevation of all variables

Tags: r, aggregation

I'm creating an index on spatially aggregated (binned) data in R where the final value needs to reflect not only an average of all input variables, but also the "presence" of all variables. The final index needs to give more weight to locations where all input variables are elevated. I'm essentially looking for a way to give less weight when one or more variables are 0 or near-0.

For example, if the values of three variables present at a given location are 5, 5, and 5, the index should give a higher score than another location with values of 0, 1, and 30. Giving less weight to lower values (in addition to 0 values) would be ideal.

My goal is to prevent a location with a single anomalously high variable (where all other variables are low or 0) from having a higher index value than a location where all variables are simultaneously "reasonably" high. Is there a statistical method that might accomplish this? Would it make sense to weight each variable off all other variables?